# Node `smtp-server` module won't work with TLS

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

This minimal code to run an SMTP server works fine. When I send an email to my server, everything (because of the `logger` option) is logged as expected, and the email data is received.

```
const {SMTPServer} = require("smtp-server");
const {simpleParser} = require("mailparser");
const server = new SMTPServer({
    authOptional: true,
    onData: async (stream, session, callback) => {
        const parsed = await simpleParser(stream);
        callback();
        console.log(parsed);
    },
    logger: true
});
server.listen(8025);
```

However, when I enable TLS options, sending an email to my server no longer logs anything. I don't even receive a connection, according to the logs.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {SMTPServer} = require("smtp-server");
const {simpleParser} = require("mailparser");
const server = new SMTPServer({
    secure: true,
    authOptional: true,
    onData: async (stream, session, callback) => {
        const parsed = await simpleParser(stream);
        callback();
        console.log(parsed);
    },
    key: fs.readFileSync("privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("chain.pem"),
    logger: true
});
server.listen(8025);
```

I think the certificate files are correct because I use them for my web server as well as my Postfix configuration, on the same domain, and HTTP/SMTP-out works fine and securely. I just can't receive email securely because of this issue.

By the way, I'm listening to port 8025 with an `iptables` redirect from 25 to 8025, and I'm just sending via my Gmail account.

What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What tool do you use to send an email to your server? Can you post results of sending it via a command-line tool or a tiny script so that the problem could be easily reproduced?

Comment: I've successfully got an email with your script over TLS (have all the logs etc) at my first attempt, tested with mailsend on my mac. Can't attach a screenshot in comments though but can reproduce it easily - so lets figure out what client you're using

Comment: I'm sending with plain ol' Gmail, not programmatically. I never receive it. After a while, Gmail always sends me an email back saying it couldn't be delivered.

Comment: I edited the second-to-last line of the post to include some extra details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the way, I'm listening to port 8025 with an iptables redirect from 25 to 8025, and I'm just sending via my Gmail account.

Because you are using `secure: true`, you are **forcing** TLS encryption. For this, you must accept connections on port **465** and **NOT** 25 to your server.

You can set `secure: false`, which will *still allow encryption via STARTTLS*, on port 25.

However, for maximum compatibility, you should start two instances of smtp-server - one listening on port 25 with `secure: false`, and one listening on port 465 with `secure: true`.

Edit:

I've just done some testing and I can confirm that simply removing `secure: true` from your script works just fine.

You can test this via https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver which will check the connection, the TLS upgrade, your certificate, and everything else.

Here are my results using your script with `secure: true` removed:

https://gyazo.com/05a34942d2cc4a2d633e830258b90f88

As you can see, the connection is upgraded to TLS just fine, and everything goes smoothly. This is on port 25.

Comment: Do email clients try 465 first or something? And I thought 465 was deprecated.

Comment: There are two different TLS mechanisms.  Pure TLS on port 465, and "upgradeable" TLS on port 25. This "upgradeable" mechanism requires there to be a cleartext connection to begin with.

Comment: Different peers prefer different protocols. For maximum compatibility it's best to support both

Comment: Added further info.